# Generate IP address to bypass shared IP

Tags: internet

My ISP forces a shared IP on their users, is there a way to generate an IP address to bypass it?

Even if bypassing shared IP is not possible, what are the methods to set/change a unique IP address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might look into setting up an IPv6 tunnel, particularly if you need addresses strictly for private use (or for the use of people outside the US.)

You can tunnel an HTTP server with PageKite.
[ChunkHost](http://chunkhost.com/r/basichunk) is currently running a free beta, if you need a VPS temporarily or will be willing to pay for it in the future.

Unfortunately, unless you are in charge of the network you don't get to control allocation of IP addresses.
When / if network providers finally switch over to IPv6 there will be plenty of addresses for everyone; hopefully we all will be able to get static IPs then.

Because NAT is bad.

Comment: Tunnel, as in something like a VPN?

Comment: Yes, in that a VPN relies upon tunneling to work. IPv6 tunneling works a somewhat differently from IPv4 tunneling in that some IPv4 tunnels track NAT state whereas IPv6 does not (AFAIK cannot) deal with NAT at all. This is not a bug; it is a feature of IPv6. Hurricane Electric, for example, will give you a free IPv6 tunnel which has a /64 subnet associated with it. A /64 subnet is a pool of addresses greater than the ENTIRE IPv4 address space. I apologize if I've got any of this wrong. It's near my bedtime. If anyone reads this, please feel free to point out my mistakes.

Comment: Can you recommend a good (and free) IPv6 tunnel? And how to set up the tunnel on Ubuntu as well.

Comment: Hurricane Electric at he.net offers this as a free service. They walk you through how to do it on their site. Once the tunnel is set up they literally give you a set of commands you can cut & paste into a terminal (or better yet, a script).

Comment: It asks for too much personal details (my phone number is the one thing that I absolutely refuse to spread over the net).

Comment: @Oxwivi HE only wants to know your number because they are required to know it. Your ISP is also required to know your # also. The reason HE and your ISP need to know is in case of abuse (like spamming and hacking attempts) so they can contact you. The place some ISPs could put your # is in whois; however, HE is pretty good about this, I use it and all they say for the addresses I have is `Hurricane Electric, Inc. HURRICANE-IPV6 (NET6-2001-470-1) 2001:470:: - 2001:470:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF` which has zero of my personal info. You can test this yourself w/ `whois 2001:470:e89d::1`.

Comment: @Oxwivi Apparently, you aren't the only person who has asked: http://www.tunnelbroker.net/forums/index.php?topic=1176.0  broquea is one of the HE employees.

Answer (score 2):

By saying 'shared IP address', do you really mean a 'dynamic' IP address that is one out of a pool of IP addresses that your ISP uses so it does not necessarily stay the same.  If this is what you have, then you need to set up a dynamic address with an organisation like DynDNS.  They will give you a domain name that will always point back to you because they track any changes your ISP makes to the IP address assigned to you.

Comment: If I'm surfing the web, will the DynDNS's address visible to the servers? I don't think so...

Comment: The point of DynDNS is that IPv4 servers that live behind a NAT can be tracked (by DynDNS) and if their IP address changes DynDNS will dynamically update the necessary records. You as a client don't need a static IPv4 address. You only really want such a thing if you are running a server. So yes, if your computer has a DynDNS A record, servers and other computers can easily get the machine's IP address with a simple DNS query.

Comment: @koanhead, it's not a server. What I mean by my DynDNS address being visible to servers is that if I'm surfing Ask Ubuntu, it will be informed of the shared IP not the DynDNS address I've registered.

Comment: When you visit websites, the web server gets your IP address as part of the HTTP request. DynDNS associates a *static* name (such as myserver.dyndns.com) with a dynamic IP address. It's possible that Web servers could then look up your computer's name using DiG or nslookup or similar tools. So what? If you are running a server it needs to be public anyway; and if, as you say, it's not a server, then you don't need DynDNS at all- the IP address allocated by your ISP should be sufficient for all your browsing needs.

Comment: @koanhead I was seeking a static IP address since the shared IP address was giving me issues on some websites. I really hope IPv6 takes over the world soon.

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think generating an IP address to bypass it is possible at least to my knowledge. You might wanna try to use a VPN if any is available to you...

But anyways, why do you want to change the IP anyhow? If you wanna set up a server, you should tell the ISP to give you unique IP address, or look for somewhere else to host your server.........

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you just want to share your sever then you should be able to map your dynamic IP with [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com) or something similar to it. And ofcourse [port forwarding](http://portforward.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The method to get a unique static ip address is to rent one from your isp. Most isp's doesn't *force* you to use a dynamic ip from their pool, they sell static ip's as an additional service. As most users doesn't need a static ip, you just don't get one by default.

Contact your isp for pricing. (Mine require 10 norwegian kroner, about 2$ a month for a static ip).